# Able to re-route traffic of a specific port to another server?

Tags: domain, port-forwarding, window-server-2019

I have the network structure as the image below.

Server1 has 2 NIC cards that links to the 168.172.x.x network and 192.168.1.x.

I want my ClientMachine1, 168.172.1.15, to connect to a port in 192.168.1.92's program. The program is on a specific TCP port. Is it possible to do it with Windows Firewall or some program? Is having a router, the only option? I have limited knowledge on networking, please I need your advise.

I tried using netsh command, but it doesn't seems to work. I am using a program (via a specific port) in ClientMachine1 to connect to the Server2 to get the data.

The below command is the netsh command I used

> netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=1234 connectport=1234
> connectaddress=192.168.1.92 protocol=tcp

Server1 is a domain controller, Server2 and ClientMachine1 joins the domain as Server1

[image]

Comment: What is the default gateway on `192.168.1.92`?

Comment: Ì didn't put default gateway for 192.168.1.92, do I need to put the default gateway? If yes, the default gateway is 192.168.1.91, am I right?

Comment: Server2 needs to know how to reach ClientMachine1. It can be a default route or a specific route via Server1.